# why ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()/TakePicturePreview does return file

Tags: android, retrofit

I am uploading a file as multipart using retrofit

```
 val requestIdentityFrontSideFileMultipartBody =identityFrontSide?.asRequestBody("image/${identityFrontSide.extension}".toMediaTypeOrNull())
                ?.let {
                    MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
                        "identityFrontSide",
                        "identityFrontSide.${identityFrontSide.extension}",
                        it
                    )
                }
```

however

```
val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
        onResult = { uri:Uri ->

val launcher =
        rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicturePreview()) {
}
```

`ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()` return Uri from gallery
`ActivityResultContracts.TakePicturePreview()` return bitmap

I don't understand why `ActivityResultContracts` does not return files
and how I can upload uri/bitmap to retofit without convert them to files because that not working for me

Comment: What is the problem with getting the file from Uri?

Comment: `without convert them to files because that not working for me` That is strange. One can use retrofit for uploading files by uri. You can do that too.

Comment: Maybe TakePicturePreview gives a bitmap. But TakePicture will work with an uri.

Comment: @blackapps how to upload URI as multipart ?so

Comment: Google for inputstreamrequestbody.